# Pango-WARNING **: couldn't load font ouldn't load font "Times Not-Rotated 18", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 10px", expect ugly output

Tags: windows, pango

I am trying to run on package/software “KUPDAP (Kyoto University Plasma Dispersion Analysis Package)”, which can be downloaded from http://space.rish.kyoto-u.ac.jp/software/ (Download executable file (Windows)). It is a winrar file. After extracting, one can see file named “kupdap”. If I click that one, a window will appear like these:

[image]

If you wait for some time or click close, then the windows changes into:

[image]

In this GUI, I can feed my data. But the problem is what is seen in the background- in the command prompt, an error message appears “ (kupdap.exe:12988) Pango-WARNING **: couldn't load font ouldn't load font "Times Not-Rotated 18", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 10px", expect ugly output”. Due to this the program is not running.
Honestly, I have never ever heard about pango. I am guessing that it has something to do with fonts in the system. I am also attaching the screenshot of the fonts (not all) in my system:

[image]

I have gone through some articles listed here: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1162 , but these things go over my head.

Could anybody help me out what is wrong and how to fix it? BTB, I am using Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `kupdap` is using a default font hardcoded to `Times`. The snippet below is copied from the beginning of the `main` function in `kupdap_source\visual\main1.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  GtkWidget *window, *vbox;
  PangoFontDescription *p;
  
  p = pango_font_description_from_string("Times 18"); // <--- this is what triggers error
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  // create credit
  GtkWidget *credit;
  credit =  gtk_about_dialog_new();
```

However, a default Windows installation has no font named `Times`, which is what causes the `Pango-WARNING`. There is a stock `Times New Roman` font, instead, but *pango* appears to be doing an exact string match, and ignores it.

Possible workarounds:

- change `"Times 18"` to `"Times New Roman 18"` (or another valid font name) in the source code and rebuild the program;
- install a font named `Times` in Windows, so that *pango* finds it;
- hex-edit the `kupdap.exe` binary and replace the unique occurrence of the text `Times` with the 5-letter name of another font that is installed e.g. `Arial`.

Comment: Dear @dxiv , 
Many thanks for taking time to look into this matter. I did not know all these. I guess you have used “kupdap_source” rather than “kupdap_binary_windows”.
In anyway, what I did was I opened “kupdap” application file in notepad++ and saw that there is “Times 18” and then changed to “Arial 18” (I am not sure whether this is a good idea). Then there was no warning. 

I also tried another method: installed fonts as you have mentioned.

In either way the warning message did not appear... 1/2

Comment: However, I am facing another issue, which is when I click the dropdown menu in species to add another one, the windows suddenly disappear. Any thoughts on that?
Thank you 2/2

Comment: @sreerajt Your hex-edit should be fine, as long as the size of the `.exe` stayed the same. I found the `"Times 18"` tidbit by snooping into the source code, but I did not build from sources since that requires several other dependencies. Beyond that, I don't really know what the program does or how it's supposed to be used, so that would be a  question for others who happen to be familiar with it.